# How do I check for an ajax request thats taking too long or just died out?

Tags: php, ajax, sajax

I'm using sajax here and at times my ajax queries seem to die out and theres no way for me to tell if something has gone wrong so I end up with an infinitely running preloader. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

i know you can canel existing ajax postback requests in the initilizerequest method clientside and that its possible to execute a javascript method after a set period of time using the 'setTimeOut' function.  Therefore in the initilizerrequest method you could call a callseemstohave died method passing in a ref to the async postback and setting a time of say 30secs then if the call is still in progress callseemstohave is called you can cancel it and reset the display if it is finished do nothing.